# Issue with VS CODE involving signing in

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, token

Whenever I tried signing in inside VS CODE, I get this error.

It takes me directly to Microsoft. Before I took me to GitHub to sign in.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step first you delete the VS CODE from our pc/laptop
Step second you install again VS CODE in pc/laptop then you signing our VS CODE

Comment: Hi Dhoti tried that but it did not work.